# how to make one dl list horizontal?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, bootstrap-4

I have dl list, but I need to make it not vertical, but horizontal and **I need to make it only with one single dl list**. I'm using bootstrap 4, so maybe It can be done with flexbox?

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <dl class="footer-top-list">
                    <dt class="footer-top-termin col-md-4">Location</dt>
                    <dd class="col-md-4">3481 Melrose Place</dd>
                    <dd class="col-md-4">Beverly Hills, CA 90210</dd>
                    <dt class="footer-top-termin col-md-4">Share with love</dt>
                    <dd class="col-md-4">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="footer-top-termin col-md-4">About</dt>
                    <dd class="col-md-4">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus
                        auctor fringilla.
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
        </div>
</footer>
```

Now I have all dt and dd vertical under each other, but I need to make it look like this: [image]

How I can do this?

Comment: Are you opposed to using `<div>`s to group `<dt>`s and `<dd>`s?

Comment: Is it possible to use a `<div>` inside a `<dl>` list? Is it semantically correct? I don't know exactly.

Comment: It depends on which spec you follow. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl  But either way it will certainly work in any browser.

Comment: Thanks, it's helped. You can put your answer into the answers section and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping your pairs of `dts` and `dd`s inside `div`s you can use the bootstrap classes to organize those groups as columns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <dl class="row footer-top-list">

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <dt class="footer-top-termin col-md-4">Location</dt>
              <dd class="col-md-4">3481 Melrose Place</dd>
              <dd class="col-md-4">Beverly Hills, CA 90210</dd>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <dt class="footer-top-termin col-md-4">Share with love</dt>
              <dd class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </dd>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <dt class="footer-top-termin col-md-4">About</dt>
              <dd class="col-md-4">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
              </dd>
            </div>

          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Note: vue snippet in full page to trigger the `md` breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `div` with class `col-md-4`? Like so:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <strong>Location</strong><br>
                  3481 Melrose Place<br>
                  Beverly Hills, CA 90210
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <strong>Share with love</strong><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <strong>About</strong><br>
                  Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus
              auctor fringilla.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
    </div>
</footer>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51kopv3u/2/)